# Single Events as Sub-Page to Main Calendar Page

Tags: events, calendar

Does anyone have experience with Time.ly's Event Calendar? I've contacted [Time.ly help](http://help.time.ly/customer/en/portal/questions/496937-single-events-as-sub-page-to-main-calendar-page-?new=496937) and they informed me this sort of thing would have to be custom work. Soo, I come to the trusty WPSE!

Do you know of a way to have single events show up as sub-posts/-pages *beneath* the main calendar page?

For example, the current permalink structure is:

- Main Calendar: `domain.com/calendar`
- Single Event:  `domain.com/ai1ec_event/single-event-title`

What I'd *like* to do, is have the permalink structure be:

- Main Calendar: `domain.com/calendar`
- Single Event:  `domain.com/calendar/single-event-title`

  or even...
- Single Event: `domain.com/calendar/ai1ec_event/single-event-title`

Either of those two **single event** permalinks would be fine with me, I just want to have it be under the **Calendar** page itself.

I'm not completely sure where to begin with this though. Just thought I'd put it out there for anyone who might be able to give me a jumping off point.

### //edit

Also, if someone with 300+ rep wouldn't mind creating these two new tags and adding them to this post, that'd be great.

- `all-in-one-event-calendar`
- `timely`

Thanks!

Comment: i work for timely, i'll create the all-in-one-event-calendar tag

Comment: No i don not have enough rep

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti no worries - it'll get there eventually :P I'm excited about the newest version, by the way! Cheers for a job well done!

Answer (score 2):

I'll preface this by saying I have no experience with or knowledge of the plugin, this answer is based entirely on a 30 second scan of the code that registers the post type for use in the plugin, so you may uncover issues with this solution that my quick clicking of a test event didn't catch. With that said...

The basic gist of this is to unset the post type registered by the plugin, and then re-register it with the same settings except for the modified rewrite slug. To understand how this works you should familiarize yourself with the [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function if you're not already.

The code that registers the post type for the plugin is in the file `app/helper/class-ai1ec-app-helper.php`.

The following code was tested in the Twenty Eleven theme's functions.php file. You can do this in your own plugin, but you'll have to be sure it runs *after* the event calendar plugin's init for this to work.

Be sure to read all of the comments within the code to understand what was changed, the important detail being the `rewrite` argument of `register_post_type` which gives us our desired URL: `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'calendar/event', 'with_front' => false )`

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa64981_event_calendar_init' );

function wpa64981_event_calendar_init() {

    // make sure the plugin is active and has set itself up
    if( defined( 'AI1EC_POST_TYPE' ) ) :

        // globalize the post types array and some plugin settings we'll need
        global $wp_post_types, $ai1ec_settings, $ai1ec_app_helper;

        // unset the original post type created by the plugin
        unset( $wp_post_types[ AI1EC_POST_TYPE ] );

        // the labels array was copied wholesale from the plugin
        // EXCEPT 'all_items' value, which originally reference $this
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Events', 'Custom post type name', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Event', 'Custom post type name (singular)', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Event', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Event', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Events', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Events found', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Events found in Trash', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Event', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Events', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ),
            'all_items' => $ai1ec_app_helper->get_all_items_name()
        );

        // identical to plugin's original values        
        $supports = array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' );


        // this is where the important change is made
        // to get our own rewrite slug:
        // 
        // 'rewrite' => true
        // 
        // changes to:
        // 
        // 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'calendar/event', 'with_front' => false )
        // 
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'calendar/event', 'with_front' => false ),
            'capability_type' => array( 'ai1ec_event', 'ai1ec_events' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'read_post'               => 'read_ai1ec_event',
                'edit_post'               => 'edit_ai1ec_event',
                'edit_posts'              => 'edit_ai1ec_events',
                'edit_others_posts'       => 'edit_others_ai1ec_events',
                'edit_private_posts'      => 'edit_private_ai1ec_events',
                'edit_published_posts'    => 'edit_published_ai1ec_events',
                'delete_post'             => 'delete_ai1ec_event',
                'delete_posts'            => 'delete_ai1ec_events',
                'delete_others_posts'     => 'delete_others_ai1ec_events',
                'delete_published_posts'  => 'delete_published_ai1ec_events',
                'delete_private_posts'    => 'delete_private_ai1ec_events',
                'publish_posts'           => 'publish_ai1ec_events',
                'read_private_posts'      => 'read_private_ai1ec_events' ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => $supports,
            'exclude_from_search' => $ai1ec_settings->exclude_from_search,
        );

        // register the post type with our new settings
        register_post_type( AI1EC_POST_TYPE, $args );

    endif;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Milo! I KNEW it had something to do with `register_post_types`! I tried editing the plugin's code, but I guess since the plugin was already active, it didn't work. The _unset/reset_ version is better: when the authors update the plugin, I won't have to re-edit :) Haven't had a chance to test it out, but will let you know how it goes. 2 Questions: **1)** If this is in my theme's functions, how can I ensure it runs *after* the plugin's? **2)** Would `hierarchical` not need to be set as `true`? Or, is it `false` because this CPT is not _technically_ a page? Thanks again!

Comment: the theme loads after plugins, so if priority isn't set, it will happen after plugin inits. see the [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) page and the `priority` argument for manipulating when your own init is fired. hierarchical gives you the ability to assign a parent for each post, like pages. it's not necessary for this particular functionality- the URL rewrite is just superficial, events aren't children of the calendar page.

Comment: Can you create the all-in-one-event-calendar tag?

Comment: This solution does not seem to work anymore, I get an error after pasting the above into theme's function file: Call to a member function get_all_items_name() on a non-object